# Search over text column in pandas data frame without looping

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have a pandas data frame where one of the columns is a text description string. I need to create a new column which would identify if one of the strings from a list is in the text description.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Description': ['2 Bedroom/1.5 Bathroom end unit Townhouse.  
Available now!', 'Very spacious studio apartment available', ' Two bedroom, 1 
bathroom condominium, superbly located in downtown']})

list_ = ['unit', 'apartment']
```

Then the result should be

```
                                        Description    in list
0  2 Bedroom/1.5 Bathroom end unit Townhouse.  Av...    True
1           Very spacious studio apartment available    True
2   Two bedroom, 1 bathroom condominium, superbly...   False
```

I can do it this way

```
for i in df.index.values:
    df.loc[i,'in list'] = any(w in df.loc[i,'Description'] for w in list_)
```

But with a large data set it takes longer than I'd like to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `str.contains`

```
list_ = ['unit', 'apartment']
df.Description.str.contains('|'.join(list_))
Out[724]: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: Description, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `np.char.find` -

```
v = df.Description.values.astype('U')[:, None]
df['in list'] = (np.char.find(v, list_) > 0).any(1)

df

                                         Description  in list
0  2 Bedroom/1.5 Bathroom end unit Townhouse.  Av...     True
1           Very spacious studio apartment available     True
2   Two bedroom, 1 bathroom condominium, superbly...    False
```

Comment: Learn new thing : -)

Comment: @Wen Cheers! It's interesting to know, but I think it's slower than `str.contains`.